# Pagination configuration via query parameters (head, last, page, limit and offset)

Tags: go

i have logic module for head, last, page, limit and offset filter.

**such as :**

> **../example/param  if no query, return all value**
>
> **../example/param?limit=10 return the first 10 value**
>
> **..example/param?offset=3 return value from number 4 to 23 (default limit is 20)**
>
> **..example/param?limit=15&offset=2 return value 3 to 17**
>
> **../example/param?page=2&limit=5 return value 6 to 10**
>
> **../example/param?head=15 return first 15 value**
>
> **../example/param?last=15 return last 15 value**
>
> **../example/param?head=8&last=4 return error**
>
> **../example/param?page=3&offset=4 return error**
>
> **../example/param?page=2&limit=5&offset=6 return error**

i have default parameter like a :

```
var defaultPageParameter = PageParameter{
Limit:  20,
Offset: 0,
Page: 1,
Head: 0,
Last: 0,
}
```

i have write some expression if else, but this code really to much, I want to simplify code.

```
if offset != defaultOffset && limit != defaultLimit && page != defaultPage && head != 0 && last != 0{
    return make([]bson.M, 0), errors.New("can't show all queries")
    //if there are all query
} else if offset != defaultOffset && limit != defaultLimit && page != defaultPage {
    return make([]bson.M, 0), errors.New("can't show all queries")
    //if there are all query
} else if offset != defaultOffset && limit == defaultLimit && page != defaultPage{
    return make([]bson.M, 0), errors.New("can't merge page and offset")
    //if combine page & offset
} else if head != 0 && last != 0 {
    return make([]bson.M, 0), errors.New("can't merge head and last")
    //if combine head & last
} else if limit <=0 || page <= 0{
    return make([]bson.M, 0), errors.New("BSON field value must be >= 0, actual value -20")
    //if limit & page value smaller than 0
}else if offset == defaultOffset && limit != defaultLimit && page == defaultPage {
    opt.SetLimit(limit)
    //if just limit
} else if offset != defaultOffset && limit == defaultLimit && page == defaultPage{
    opt.SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit)
    //if just offset
} else if offset == defaultOffset && limit == defaultLimit && page != defaultPage{
    opt.SetSkip(paginate).SetLimit(defaultLimit)
    //if just page
} else if offset == defaultOffset && limit != defaultLimit && page != defaultPage{
    opt.SetSkip(paginate).SetLimit(limit)
    //if limit & page
} else if offset != defaultOffset && limit != defaultLimit && page == defaultPage{
    opt.SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit)
    //if offset & limit
} else if head == 0 && last != 0{
    opt.SetLimit(last).SetSort(bson.M{"$natural": -1})
    //if just last
} else if head != 0 && last == 0{
    opt.SetSkip(0).SetLimit(head)
    //if just head
} else {
    options.Find()
    //else return default
}
```

this code refer to notes above, my code really to much expression,
can anyone simplify?

Answer (score 1):

You have three types of processing: error processing, offset page and limit processing, and the head/last processing.

I would split your conditions according to purpose and abstract them into three tables.

**Error processing**
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
  \text{Condition} & \text{offset} & \text{limit} & \text{page} & \text{head} & \text{last} & \text{action} \\ 
\hline
  1 & \neq default &  \neq default &  \neq default &  \neq 0 &  \neq 0 & \text {can't show all queries}\\
\hline
  2 &  \neq default &  \neq default &  \neq default &   &   & \text {can't show all queries}\\
\hline
  3 &  \neq default &  = default &  \neq default &   &   & \text {can't merge page and offset}\\
\hline
  4 &   &   &   & \neq 0   &  \neq 0  & \text {can't merge head and last}\\
\hline
  5a &   &  \le 0 &  &   &   & \text {BSON field value must be >= 0, actual value -20}\\
\hline
  5b &   &   &  \le 0 &   &   & \text {BSON field value must be >= 0, actual value -20}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Condition 1 is redundant, as it is covered by condition 2. Condition 3 is only required to generate the correct error message, so can be included in that. Condition 5a and 5b you have already merged.

**Offset, page and limit**
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
  \text{Condition} & \text{offset} & \text{limit} & \text{page} & \text{action} \\ 
\hline
  A &  default &  \neq default & default  & \text {SetLimit(limit)}\\
\hline
  B &  \neq default &  = default &  = default   & \text {SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit)}\\
\hline
  C &  = default &  = default &  \neq default   & \text {SetSkip(paginate).SetLimit(defaultLimit)}\\
\hline
  D & = default  &  \neq default & \neq default     & \text {SetSkip(paginate).SetLimit(limit)}\\
\hline
  E &  \neq default &  \neq default & = default   & \text {SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit)}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Conditions B and E can be combined, as can conditions C and D (because *limit*  = *defaultLimit* in condition C).

Best would be if *SetLimit* could take separate paginate and offset parameters,  because then you could just call *SetSkip(paginate,offset).SetLimit(limit)* with no condition checking whatsoever.

**Head and last**
\begin{array}{|c|c|l|}
\hline
  \text{Condition} & \text{head} & \text{last} & \text{action} \\ 
\hline
  X & = 0 &  \neq 0  & \text {SetLimit(last).SetSort(bson.M\{"\$natural": -1\}}\\
\hline
  Y &  \neq 0 & = 0 & \text {SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit)}\\
\hline
\end{array}

No real simplification here, unless you separate the conditions out into a subroutine. Then you just have an if-else, as they can't both be unequal to zero, by condition 1.

Now, initialize three arrays with the relevant values from the tables and set the action column to be the function to execute. You will need to define a symbol meaning "don't care" in the array, but this approach lets you add new conditions relatively easily.

Alternatively factor out the conditions into subroutines, if the array approach does not suit your coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to code review. Since I do not know golang, I'll write my answer in **pseudocode**.

You according to your description, there are three cases:

- Return all values if no param is given
- Return an error if given params are invalid
- Return the requested values

If you want to provide different error messages for each error scenario (which is a good idea), you'll need a case for each scenario. So, other than simplyfing the logic conditions to not be redundant, there is not much more to do.

If there is no error, you just need to calculate the values of to skip and the limit of values to return.

Putting it into code:

```
function checkValidValues(head, last, page, limit, offset) {
  if page != null && offset != null {
    throw error "can't merge page and offset"
  }
  ... check other errors
}

function calculateSkipAndLimit(head, last, page, limit, offset) {
  if limit == null {
    limit = defaultLimit
  }

  var skip = 0
  if head != null {
    limit = head
  } else if offset != null {
    skip = offset
  } else if page != null {
    skip = page * PAGE_SIZE
  } else {  // last is nor null
    skip = totalNumValues - last
    limit = last
  }

  // Assuming multiple values can be returned
  return skip, limit
}

function getValues(head, last, page, limit, offset) {
  if head == null && last == null && page == null && limit == null && offset == null {
    return findAllValues()
  }
  // If invalid values, and exception will be thrown and execution would
  //  not proceed
  checkValidValues(head, last, page, limit, offset)

  // Assuming multiple values can be returned. Otherwise, it would have
  // to be two separate function calls
  skip, limit = calculateSkipAndLimit(head, last, page, limit, offset)
  return opt.SetSkip(skip).setLimit(limit)
}
```

That being said, if you have a need for pagination, that probably means that having an option to return all values might be a lenghty operation that maybe shouldn't be supported. In case no query parameters were provided, you could intead use default values.